# PHP search in multidimensional array. without knowing key

Tags: php

Array:

```
$userdb = array(
    array(
        'uid' => '100',
        'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
        'pic_square' => 'abc.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '5465',
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'pic_square' => 'Michael.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '40489',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'pic_square' => 'xyz.jpg'
    )
);
```

Search value:

> Michael

Expected output:

```
$userdb = array(
    array(
        'uid' => '5465',
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'pic_square' => 'Michael.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '40489',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'pic_square' => 'xyz.jpg'
    )
);
```

As you can check what I want can anyone please tell me How can I achieve this result by using PHP. I don't care whether my search term is in 'uid', 'name', or 'pic_square' key but I want to get array whenever my search term result is matching. Is there any inbuilt function which can achieve this result?

Comment: Can you please show the coding effort what you tried so far?

Comment: This, to me seems like a `foreach` nested inside another `foreach`...

Comment: @AlivetoDie my mind is blank I tried nothing. Please help me.

Comment: @RomeoSierra Any alternative way because element is too much.

Comment: @shahrushabh That's not how things work around here.

Comment: You have many [unclosed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9573329/shah-rushabh?tab=questions), right? Do you know how to do? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235 Thank you for all your answerers and future readers :)

Comment: @AlivetoDie Yes bro I checked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Very simple solution is*** to apply simple `foreach()` with [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

1.iterate over the array using `foreach()`

2.Check that search value exist in any one of three `id, name,pic_square` or not? if yes then add that whole sub-array to a new array.

3.This new array is your desired result.

```
$search_value = 'Michael';


$final_array = [];

foreach($userdb as $userd){
  if(strpos($userd['uid'],$search_value)!== false || strpos($userd['name'],$search_value)!== false || strpos($userd['pic_square'],$search_value)!== false){

     $final_array[] = $userd;
  }

}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/997896

Comment: Bro thanks for a solution but I used array_search method it is fast. Same step I followed.

Comment: @shahrushabh  glad to help you :):)

Comment: hi @AnantKumarSingh
$market = [
            44434 => [
                34945,
                44434,
                41133,
                41132,
                49902
            ],
            49968=> [
                49968,
                49967
            ]
        ];

i want to do like this? if i give inner array value then get the above matched key i.e if we search 49902 then get  44434 this value

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter) to remove elements that not match to your search.

```
$userdb = array(
    array('uid' => '100', 'name' => 'Sandra Shush', 'pic_square' => 'abc.jpg'),
    array('uid' => '5465', 'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn', 'pic_square' => 'Michael.jpg'),
    array('uid' => '40489', 'name' => 'Michael', 'pic_square' => 'xyz.jpg')
);

$search = 'Michael';
$out = array_filter($userdb, function($item) use($search) {
    return $item['name'] == $search || strpos($item['pic_square'], $search) !== false;
});
print_r($out);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [1] => Array (
            [uid] => 5465
            [name] => Stefanie Mcmohn
            [pic_square] => Michael.jpg
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [uid] => 40489
            [name] => Michael
            [pic_square] => xyz.jpg
        )
)
```

Comment: `$item['name'] == $search ` need to use `strpos()` too otherwise it will not work for a name like `Michael Dominic`..... I have this assumption only. Mind that I didn't say you are wrong.

Comment: You're right Alive. I use a full match here to show multiple possibilities. But I think a strpos for the name is probably more useful. Thank for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use preg_grep to match the search in a loose comparison.

```
$search = "Michael";
Foreach($userdb as $key => $arr){
    If(preg_grep("/" . $search ."/", $arr)){
        $res[] = $userdb[$key];
    }
}

Var_dump($res);
```

I loop through the array and if a match is made with preg_grep it's added to the result array.

https://3v4l.org/BPJBC

Preg_grep will search the full array and not only items hardcoded.
This can be both a good and a bad thing obviously.

As an example if your DB expands with 'alias' key preg_grep will search that to without needing to change the code.

See here for an example:
https://3v4l.org/lOao3

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
foreach($userdb as $i=>$r){
    foreach($r as $j=>$v){
        #if($v matches the querystring)
            #return $r / append $r to a match list
    }
}
```

But **NOTE THAT** since there are no indexing and all, this will run in **O(N^2)** which is the worst case...

**EDIT**

After some research, came up with the following solution.

```
$userdb = array(
    array(
        'uid' => '100',
        'name' => 'Sandra Shush',
        'pic_square' => 'abc.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '5465',
        'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
        'pic_square' => 'Michael.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'uid' => '40489',
        'name' => 'Michael',
        'pic_square' => 'xyz.jpg'
    )
);

$search = "Michael";

$out = array_filter($userdb, function($item) use($search) {
    foreach($item as $k=>$v){
        if(preg_match("/$search/", $v) == 1){
            return true;
        }
    }
});

echo json_encode($out);
```

The solution employs [`array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function ([Syscall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50127898/3126973) is acknowledged hereby, that was the pointer for me to research on [`array_filter`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) further) to reduce the array using a filter, where the filter being a [`preg_match`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) executed on each attribute of the associative array elements. If a match found, it returns true, which will add the matching element into `$out`.

Comment: 2 foreach() is not required at all.

Comment: That's only if you know exactly how many items are there you already **know all the keys** to search for.. Did you downvote this??

Comment: I just asked out of curiosity.. :) Anyway, for all the approaches above, you need the complete knowledge of the keys upfront. If we don't know the keys, or if the keys in the associative arrays vary from one to another, you might be in trouble...